# I am trying to display image on frontend using pinata and ipfs but facing this error

Tags: solidity, hardhat, react, ipfs, pinata

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./Display.css";
const Display = ({ contract, account }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState("")
    const getdata = async () => {
        let dataArray;
        const OtherAddress = document.querySelector(".address").value;
        try {
            if (OtherAddress) {
              dataArray = await contract.display(OtherAddress);
              console.log(dataArray);
            } else {
              dataArray = await contract.display(account);
            }
          } catch (e) {
            alert("You don't have access");
          }                                                                                  
        const isEmpty = Object.keys(dataArray).length === 0;

        if (!isEmpty) {
            const str = dataArray.toString();
            const str_array = str.split(",");
            console.log(str);
            console.log(str_array);
            const images = str_array.map((item, i) => {
                return (
                    <a href={item} key={i} target="_blank">
                        <img key={i} src={`https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${item.substring(6)}`}
                            alt="new"
                            className="image-list"
                        ></img> 
                    </a>
                )
            })
            setData(images);
        }
        else {
            alert("No Image to display");
        }
    };
    return (
        <>
            <div className="image-list">{data}</div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Address" className="address"></input>
            <button className="center button" onClick={getdata}>
                Get Data
            </button>
        </>
    )
}

export default Display;
```

error when try catch block ->

Cannot convert undefined or null to object
and if i remove try catch block this is the error it shows ->

call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="display(address)", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)

Answer (score 0):

From the error it sounds like its more related to `display(address)` but let us know if you need more assistance with the upload part! We have some React examples [here](https://docs.pinata.cloud/recipes/react-upload-components) as well as an [Next.js Template](https://docs.pinata.cloud/docs/nextjs-starter) you can spin up with `npx create-pinata-app`